# Magento Transactional Email Links prefixed with x-msg

Tags: email, magento, transactional

**Objective**
Send out a Magento transactional email with a link back to the website with a variable on the end of the url.

**Process**
I pass a variable into Magento’s transactional email called link and display it using the following code in the email template.

```
<p>link = {{var link}}</p>
<a href=“{{var link}}” target=“_blank">click here</a>
```

**Problem**
The link is displayed correctly in the p tags e.g.

> http://www.mysite.com/?param=1

However when i move the mouse over a tag i get the following link which prevents the link in the email from working:

> x-msg://12/“http://www.mysite.com/?param=1”

**Notes**

- I have tried this in Mac Mail and Hotmail and get the same result.
- The url i am passing into the email needs to be dynamic and cannot be hard coded.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had a funny double quote around the link.